# Hibernate-annotations 3.4.0.GA and slf4j?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven-2, slf4j

I have a maven project A that use hibernate-annotations 3.4.0.GA which use the slf4j-api version 1.5.5 (checked through the dependency tree in the pom.xml file). Further project A specifies slf4j-log4j12 version 1.4.2 as a dependency.

I have another maven project B which depend on project A. In project B I have specified the following dependencies:

```
slf4j-api version 1.6.1,
logback-core version 0.9.24
logback-classic version 0.9.24
```

which builds fine with maven from the command line. But when I run the project from eclipse launch configuration I get:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/mm/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.4.2/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/mm/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/0.9.24/logback-classic-0.9.24.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: slf4j-api 1.6.x (or later) is incompatible with this binding.
SLF4J: Your binding is version 1.5.5 or earlier.
SLF4J: Upgrade your binding to version 1.6.x. or 2.0.x
```

From this message its indicated to that I need to upgrade the binding in project A to 1.6.x, but I don't see how that is possible since its included in the  hibernate dependency.

Is it possible to switch the binding (updating the classpath info) when running project B so it use the 1.6.1 version instead of the version from the hibernate project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I have a maven project A that use hibernate-annotations 3.4.0.GA which use the slf4j-api version 1.5.5 (checked through the dependency tree in the pom.xml file). Further project A specifies slf4j-log4j12 version 1.4.2 as a dependency.

That's not recommended, you should use the same versions of slf4j artifacts. From the FAQ:

> #### [Are SLF4J versions backward compatible?](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#compatibility)
>
> With rare theoretical exceptions,
>   SLF4J versions are backward
>   compatible. This means than you can
>   upgrade from SLF4J version 1.0 to any
>   later version without problems.
>
> However, while the SLF4J API is very
>   stable from the client's perspective,
>   SLF4J bindings such as slf4j-simple or
>   slf4j-log4j12 may require a specific
>   version of slf4j-api. **Mixing
>   different versions of slf4j artifacts
>   can be problematic and is strongly
>   discouraged.** For instance, if you
>   are using slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar, then
>   you should also use
>   slf4j-simple-1.5.6.jar, using
>   slf4j-simple-1.4.2.jar will not work.
>
> At initialization time, if SLF4J
>   suspects that there may be a version
>   mismatch problem, it emits a warning
>   about the said mismatch. For the exact
>   details of the version mismatch
>   detection mechanism, please refer to
>   the [relevant entry](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#version_checks) in this FAQ.

That's something to fix.

> which builds fine with maven from the command line. But when I run the project from eclipse launch configuration I get (...)

The problem is that you get the SLF4J artifacts from B **and** those from A (transitively) and you thus end up mixing **several versions of the `slf4j-api`** (1.5.5 and 1.6.1) and **several bindings** (`slf4j-log4j12` and `logback-classic`). SLF4J is complaining about the later problem at runtime but you should fix both.

> From this message its indicated to that I need to upgrade the binding in project A to 1.6.x, but I don't see how that is possible since its included in the hibernate dependency.

Yes, the message suggests upgrading a binding to a more recent version. But, more important, it reports that you have more than **ONE** binding on the class path: you need to choose between log4j and logback as logging backed and to provide the appropriate binding, but not both of them.

> Is it possible to switch the binding (updating the classpath info) when running project B so it use the 1.6.1 version instead of the version from the hibernate project?

To strictly answer this question about controlling versions in transitive dependencies, this can be done using the `dependencyManagement` element. Here is an example:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

And artifacts having `slf4j-api` as dependency, such as Hibernate EntityManager, would use version 1.6.1 as shown below:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
...
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.2.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.0.SP1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.4.GA:compile
```

But as I said, the real problem is that you need to have only one binding on the classpath. Either choose log4j or logback, just not both, and provide the appropriate binding.

Comment: I did run mvn dependency:tree on project A which has a dependency on hibernate. And it shows that hibernate-annotations version 3.4.0.GA use the slf4j-api version 1.5.5 and not 1.6.1.


If I understand you correctly all projects depending on module A should use the same version as hibernate - 1.5.5?

Seems rather fragile to me that all projects which depend on each other must use the same version. Further I cannot use slf4j 1.6.1 before hibernate updates to that version.

Comment: @tul: Yes, all projects should use the same version. No, they don't have to use the same version as Hibernate. As I told you, you can control the versions of artifacts in transitive dependencies using the `dependencyManagement` element and I provided an example. There is no need to wait for Hibernate to update the version they use. Just use the `dependencyManagement` element, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but after crawling my dependency tree and fixing my pom I was still having issues.  My solution?

```
mvn clean
```

(just in case anyone else made my mistake!)